# How can Delphi be used to develop iOS apps if the iOS devices are running the latest iOS version?

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi

The idea of using Delphi to develop a mobile app is appealing to us because we can do Android, iOS and Windows without duplicating work. Delphi is also a language that we are familiar with. However after trying to get a simple test app running on an iPad, I do not think it is actually realistic. Here are my observations:

1. The iPad is running iOS 12.0.1 (and iOS 12.1 is already downloaded and ready to install).
2. Xcode, which runs on the mac, is used by Delphi for building apps and deploying them to the test target. Each Xcode version supports exactly one iOS SDK version and is the Xcode version plus 2. My old Mac is currently running xcode 8.2.1 so that corresponds to iOS SDK 10.2, which should run on iOS 10.2 and higher.
3. Delphi Tokyo supports iOS SDK versions from 8.0 up to 11.3 (so Xcode 6 to 9). It will not compile apps using SDK 12. The Xcode version running on the mac fits squarely within this range of versions.
4. It appears that Xcode is not able to properly support iOS versions that are newer than itself. When trying to run the application it errors out with "unable to location DeviceSupport directory for the connected device. Please check Xcode installation path and run Xcode devices". Under "Devices" the following is displayed for the iPad: "This iPad mini2 is running iOS 12.0.1, which may not be supported by this version of Xcode".

So, it would appear that the latest Xcode version is required to support the iPad running iOS 12.x but that means that Delphi cannot compile for it because it only goes up to SDK 11.3 and not 12. I do not think it is possible or sensible to downgrade the iPad iOS. Also even if we get a Delphi version that works, the next iOS update will require a new Xcode and therefore a new Delphi version that isn't even available. When the new Delphi version is finally available it will already be obsolete since iOS will have already moved on.

Please correct me where I am wrong. Because this cannot surely be the state of things.

Comment: "*[Delphi] will not compile apps using SDK 12 ... Delphi cannot compile for it because it only goes up to SDK 11.3 and not 12*" - See [Targeting iOS 12 with RAD Studio](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/targeting-ios-12-with-rad-studio) on Embarcadero's site.

Comment: Not the latest XCode is required, but it should be newer, than the one you have. I can target iOS 12.1 devices with Delphi 10.2.3 just fine. The real target is iOS 11.x

Comment: When you upgrade from one OS to the next, surely you don't think that every existing app in the app store will need to be recompiled to run on your machine? That would be madness. But it is the consequence of what you appear to be saying. What may have happened is that apple have offered you a new SDK and you have accepted it. Then things will go wrong. You need to regress to SDK 11.3

Comment: Apple is notorious for not caring about backward compatibility when they release a new OS version, yet your expectations are that amazingly third party vendors will be able to adapt to those issues instantaneously and use future versions seamlessly, and that can't happen. Welcome to the Apple family.

Comment: @Sherlock70 which Xcode versions can be used then?

Comment: @RemyLebeau this is helpful I perhaps I will try to get on to the beta program. I am only concerned that we may not be able to keep the update subscription going indefinitely in which case we will probably get stuck in the future.

Comment: @Dsm indeed it would be madness that every app would need to be recompiled and I did not claim that. My problem is that I need to use an older Xcode and the one that I have is not compatible with the version of iOS running on the iPad that I wish to test with. As Ken White correctly pointed out, third party vendors cannot instantaneously adapt to changes which always seemed reasonable to me but I did expect that Xcode would at least support devices running newer iOS versions but it doesn't so does this mean that any iPhones and iPads must be running old iOS versions?

Comment: @PeterBall I'm running XCode 10.1 (10B61)

Comment: @Sherlock70 doesn't that version of Xcode give you iOS SDK 12.1 which the standard release version of Delphi Tokyo cannot compile for? Or are you able to use an earlier SDK? (My understanding is that Xcode comes with exactly one SDK version.)

Comment: @PeterBall It should just work...Can't say anything other than "try it".

Comment: I use multiple Versions of XCode on my Mac. I have XCode 8.2.1 to be able to use and compile with Dephi 10.1 Berlin against the iOS SDK 10.2 and XCode 10.1 to be able to use an iPad with iOS 12.x as a development and test device. I have set up the command line tools to use the XCode 8.2.1 version.